# Motorola Razr MTP error

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers, motorola-droid-razr

When I connect my Razr it says the device driver software not successfully installed. Under device manager it says device cannot start error code 10.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A variety of issues can cause Windows to report [This device cannot start (Code 10)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943104).

The first thing to check is to go to Windows Update and install any relevant updates for your computer. You may also need to select any optional updates which aren't yet installed.

Once the computer is up to date, try reinstalling the device driver provided by the phone manufacturer. You can find these for the Motorola DROID RAZR at [Motorola's web site](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/usb_drivers/) (choose Handset USB driver for Windows 32-bit or 64-bit depending on which version of Windows you have). You can also use the [Motorola Device Manager](http://www.motorola.com/Support/US-EN/Support-Homepage/Software_and_Drivers/USB-and-PC-Charging-Drivers) to install the drivers.